# Jquery display div based on form input

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to use jQuery to display a div based on the input in a formfield.

For example if the value typed in the formfield is between 1 and 5 show a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var div = $('div').hide();

$('input').keyup(function() {

   var value = this.value;

   if (value > 1 && value < 5) {
       div.fadeIn();
   } else {
       div.fadeOut();   
   }

});
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/4NgML/).

If you don't want it to reset itself when blank, add this after declaring and defining `value`...

```
if (value === '') {
   return;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with the div being hidden.
Add a handler to form field's keyup event.
In handler, check if value meets criteria, then .show() your div.